# Force Thread CultureInfo on all async socket callbacks

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, cultureinfo

Is there a way to set the default CultureInfo ("en-US") for all async socket callbacks or do I really have to set manually on every callback?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding .NET 4.5 you can use `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`. Unfortunately, you cannot set CultureInfo for application, so every thread is started with system locale information.